Evaluation of Collision Term in Quantum Boltzmann Equation
In cosmology, the Boltzmann equation is of great importance. However, apart from special cases, it is quite difficult to evaluate. Most textbooks will make greatly simplifying assumptions in order to get it into a form that can be easily evaluated. However, I am curious about the situation where we cannot make such assumptions.
Lets say we have the interaction $1+2 \leftrightarrow 3+4$, and particle $1$ is the one of interest.  Neglecting blocking/enhancement factors, we have collision term $C[f_1]=\frac{1}{2E_1}\int\int\int\frac{d^3p_2}{(2\pi)^32E_2}\frac{d^3p_3}{(2\pi)^32E_3}\frac{d^3p_4}{(2\pi)^32E_4} (f_3f_4-f_1f_2)|\mathcal{M}|^2\delta^4(U_1+U_2-U_3-U_4)$ where each $U_i$ is the respective particles $4$ momentum.
The $f_1f_2$ term is not too difficult thanks to the fact that we are not integrating over $p_1$, so we can end up expressing this as a cross section averaged over $f_2$.
The $f_3f_4$ term on the other hand has me lost. I would like to reduce this to an expression which I can evaluate numerically, even if quite complex. This has proven to be quite challenging.
I am wondering if there is a way to simplify this expression at all. My goal is to remove the delta functions, and when I try this I essentially end up with the equality $s+t+u=\sum m_i^2$ (where $s,t,u$ are Mandelstram variables). I am unsure how to use this to simplify the expression.
Any help would be appreciated.

Is $p_i \equiv U_i$? Did you try $\int \frac{d^3 p}{2 E} ... =\int d^4 p ,\theta(p^0) \delta(p^2-m^2)...$?

@Hyperon $U_i=(E_i, \vec{p}_i)$--so the delta term just enforces 4-momentum conservation. Im not sure how "un-integrating" the energy term will help, is there some sort of trick I can perform with it?

Integrating over, e.g. $d^4 p_4$, you can get rid of the 4-dimensional delta function. In this way, you left with only $6-1=5$ integrations ($-1$ because of the remaining 1-dimensional delta function). My question was simply, if you had  already  tried something along these lines...

@Hyperon I mean the $d^3p_i$ integrals result in essentially the same process. It seems like the difficulty is parametrizing the outgoing momenta in a way that can be integrated. But yeah, I see that the result should be an integral over $\vec{p}_2$  and the solid angle of $p_3$, with $|p_3|$ being determined by $\vec{p}_2$ and the solid angle of $p_3$. Its just a pain getting this in an integratabtle form.

Depending on the Lorentz structure of your integrand, you could try to exploit the fact the  integration measure is a Lorentz invariant.  Performing the integration in a specific reference frame (where the integration becomes easier) and reading off the general result (for an arbitrary reference frame) only at the end,  might be a useful strategy.
